# Accessing `super()` inside python class property

Tags: python, inheritance, python-decorators

I'm learning about `python`'s inheritance, and have come across a behaviour I don't quite understand. Here is a minimal working example:

```py
class Test():
    
    def meth1(self):
        print('accessing meth1')
        return super().a #calling random nonexisting attribute; error (as expected)
    
    @property
    def prop1(self):
        print('accessing prop1')
        return super().a #calling random nonexisting attribute; no error?

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print('getattr ' + name)
    
test = Test()
```

Calling `.meth1()` fails as expected...

```
In  [1]: test.meth1()
accessing meth1
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-160-4a0675c95211>", line 1, in <module>
    test.meth1()

  File "<ipython-input-159-1401fb9a0e13>", line 5, in meth1
    return super().a #calling random nonexisting attribute; error (as expected)

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'a'
```

...as `super()` is `object` which does indeed not have this attribute.

But `.prop1` does not...

```
In  [2]: test.prop1
accessing prop1
getattr prop1
```

...which I don't understand. It seems the property is called twice, once 'normally' and once via `__getattr__`.

Some observations:

- I assume it's got something to do with the `property` decorator.
- The attribute `.a` seems to never be accessed.
- If I replace the `return super().a` line in `prop1` with something like `return 5`, the `__getattr__` method is never called.
- If I actually make `Test` inherit from a class having an attribute `a`, its value is returned from `test.meth1()`, but not from `test.prop1`.

Could someone explain what's going on here? I've not been able to find any useful information addressing the combination of attribute decorators and `super()`.

Many thanks,

Comment: It seems the ``property`` is suppressing the ``AttributeError`` in this case. This is not about ``super``; an explicit ``raise AttributeError`` in the property is silenced as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: `meth1` raises `AttributeError` *after* lookup, when `__getattr__` is not involved. `prop1` raises `AttributeError` *during* lookup, triggering a fallback to `__getattr__` which succeeds to return `None`.

```py
>>> test.prop1        # AttributeError happens here during lookup
accessing prop1
getattr prop1
>>> meth = test.meth1 # AttributeError happens *not* here during lookup
>>> meth()            # AttributeError happens here *after* lookup
...
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'a'
```

---

The `__getattr__` method is only called when an "attribute is not found" – in other words that `AttributeError` is raised on access. The same behaviour occurs when the property raises the error directly:

```py
class Test():
    @property
    def prop1(self):
        print('accessing prop1')
        raise AttributeError  # replaces `super().a`

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print('getattr ' + name)
    
test = Test()
test.prop1  # < explicitly raises AttributeError
# accessing prop1
# getattr prop1
test.prop2  # < implicitly raises AttributeError
# getattr prop2
```

The `AttributeError` does not reveal whether it comes from a missing `prop1` attribute or some nested internal attribute (say, `super().a`). Thus, both trigger the fallback to `__getattr__`.

This is intended behaviour of `__getattr__`.

> #### [`object.__getattr__(self, name)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)
>
> Called when the default attribute access fails with an AttributeError (either `__getattribute__()` raises an `AttributeError` because name is not an instance attribute or an attribute in the class tree for self; *or `__get__()` of a name property raises AttributeError*).

It allows properties to fallback to the regular lookup mechanism when they cannot produce a value.

Comment: Do I understand correctly? I'm going to anthropomorphize. In order to execute `meth1`, it first needs to be looked up in the objects internal dictionary. It is found and loaded into memory. "Python knows this method exists on this object". Then an `AttributeError` is thrown, but there's no confusing this might be due to the attribute missing on the object, so we don't enter into `__getattr__`. (1/2)

Comment: With properties it's different. `prop1` "emulates" the existance of a simple, "valued" attribute (as if it were `self.prop1`), and apparently the attribute `prop1` is only assumed to exist once its value has been evaluated without error. As this is does not happen, python assumes the `AttributeError` to mean that it does not exist, and checks with `__getattr__` if a fallback is defined, which there is as `None` is returned. (2/2)

Comment: @ElRudi Yes, that is about it. *Looking up* a method and *calling* a method are two separate things. You can separate ``test.meth1`` into a) ``tmeth1 = test.meth1()`` and b) ``tmeth1()``. Notably, a) does the lookup (possibly including ``__getattr__``) but it is b) which raises ``AttributeError``. A property is called as part of the lookup, so there is only a) and the ``AttributeError`` happens during it.

Comment: Great, many thanks. Does this mean this behaviour does not apply to decorators in general? Does it apply to `property` just because it executes the function it's decorating?

Comment: Decorators are a red herring for this. You could build a ``property`` via call syntax, or insert a pre-built property and it would behave the same here. The important part is what object ``@property``+function constructs; namely something that raises the error during ``__get__`` (by way of ``__get__`` calling the ``prop1`` function in this case). Compare ``@classmethod``, which does not suppress the error.